# Using flash for videoconferencing

Tags: flash, video, asterisk

I'd like to set up a videoconferencing (1-1 initially) system using Flash as the client.  I've tried some web searches but couldn't find much; any pointers on the following would be great:

- Does the standard browser Flash 10 plugin contain everything needed for P2P video conferencing, or is server support needed?
- Does anyone have any experience of opensource server videoconferencing products to be used with Flash on the browser side?  E.g. would Asterisk work?  Something like http://www.red5chat.com/ ?  (ideally I'd like to be able to record videoconferences also).  Any licencing issues?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

check BigBlueButton http://www.bigbluebutton.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at OpenMeetings: https://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/